# persistent constant values - Crafting Interpreters

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, crafting-interpreters

I am reading the "Crafting Interpreters" by Bob Nystrom on chapter [26 Garbage Collection](http://craftinginterpreters.com/garbage-collection.html#reachability). On the first page, he says with the following example:

> ```
> var a = "first value";
> a = "updated";
> // GC here.
> print a;
> ```
>
> Say we run the GC after the assignment has completed on the second
> line. The string “first value” is still sitting in memory, but there
> is no way for the user’s program to ever get to it. Once `a` got
> reassigned, the program lost any reference to that string. We can
> safely free it. A value is **reachable** if there is some way for a user
> program to reference it.

My doubt is how "first value" will be collected as this will be the constant saved in function object's chunk. So as long as the function frame is active, that constant value would be alive even after it is supposed to be dropped. This is because for function object root, the snippet he uses to mark is the following

```
switch (object->type) {
      case OBJ_FUNCTION: {
        ObjFunction* function = (ObjFunction*)object;
        markObject((Obj*)function->name);
        markArray(&function->chunk.constants);
        break;
      }
```

In which if a function is alive, its constants would be alive and so in our example "first value" would be alive. Then how the claim he made in the start fits into this framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the language developed in the book you refer to, strings do not share memory with each other. When the statement `var a = "first value";` is executed, `a` is set to a *copy* of the constant string `"first value"` stored in the function's constant table. It's that copy which becomes garbage after the following assignment. The original constant is, as you say, referred to by the function itself, and cannot be garbage collected while the function is accessible.

This is a common strategy in languages in which strings are mutable. One alternative is to copy strings lazily, usually called "copy on write" (COW). That saves copies at the cost of more complicated code, and additional synchronization to support multiple threads, if necessary.

Many languages feature immutable strings, which makes it much easier to share memory, but makes optimisation of string updates more complicated. So there are a lot of trade-offs.

Also see the "challenges" at the end of the chapter on strings.

Comment: `@rici` but the underlying character array on heap for string in constants of function object and string stored in `a` is same right ?

Comment: @BhavyaBhatt: No, as I said, it's a copy. It has the same characters, but it's  different memory.

Comment: `@rici` what if my string in constants and string in local variable share the same character array on heap ?

Comment: @BhavyaBhatt: then you'll have to think about mutability of strings, as I discuss briefly in the answer.

Comment: `@rici` In my language, strings are immutable so to make new strings I use deep copying for example while overriding `+` operator for strings. I believe python also works like this.

Comment: @bhayva: more or less. Python uses reference counting GC (plus occasional loop detection) so it can usually tell when a string has only one reference, allowing it to modify in place. There are *lots* of different approaches. The major JavaScript implementations use Ropes, which avoids a lot of copying and generally makes repeated appends linear time.